# How do I get branch metrics links to support existing deep link paths?

Tags: android, ios, deep-linking, branch.io

I've got existing iOS and Android apps in the stores which support deeplinking. Is it possible to use Branch.io so that a single link can deeplink to the either app dependant on the OS the link is clicked on?

E.g. The deeplink I use is example://view/account and i'd like to use something like http://example.com/account in the email to my customers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re absolutely right, using [Branch Links](https://branch.io/?bmp=so-ac) means you can generate a single link that can be used to take advantage of your existing deep link URI path, regardless of the OS the link is clicked in.

[This diagram](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/fc3b8d646fcda6f9266d3ef2c607e497cb7c6ad2/68747470733a2f2f73332d75732d776573742d312e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f6272616e63682d6775696465732f627070303035746578744d65466561747572652e6a7067) illustrates how Branch Links work across operating systems.

To leverage your existing deep link pathways, the way to properly configure the redirects of the link is by specifying the "$deeplink_path" key in the ‘data’/'params' dictionary, with the value of the URI path that you would like appended to your URI scheme that you've configured on the dashboard.

For example, you could specify "$deeplink_path": "radio/station/456” and we'll open the app with the URI "yourapp://radio/station/456?link_click_id=branch-identifier". Here's how the code would look for iOS in that example:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];    

// Customize the display of the link
[params setObject:@"Great Radio Station forKey:@"$og_title"];
[params setObject:@"url.to.picture/radiopic.png" forKey:@"$og_image_url"];
[params setObject:@"This is my jam" forKey:@"$og_description"];

// Set the deep link path
[params setObject:@"radio/station/456" forKey:@"$deeplink_path"];

Branch *branch = [Branch getInstance];
[branch getShortURLWithParams:params andCallback:^(NSString *url, NSError *error) {
    // show the link to the user or share it immediately
}];
```

The awesome part about Branch is that it also lets you deep link through the install process, passing your URI path through either app store.

Let me know if this helps!